# Run PowerShell script from R

Tags: r, powershell, rstudio

I want to run a PowerShell script from R studio but it doesn't work for me. I tried to add this:

```
system("power shell -command "")
```

but the script destroyed ("'"'")

This is the script I want to run:

```
(Get-Content "C:\Users\XXXX\AXXXX\Local\GoogleXXXX\000022.log" -Raw)-replace '[^ -~\t]' | Set-Content XXXX.txt -Force
```

How can I run this script?

Comment: in windows you could access the command prompt from Rstudio from one of the panes

Comment: I don't know anything about R, but I would guess that `system` expects the name of an executable. So it probably should be `powershell` instead of `power shell`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69685195/9731176