# Execute windows powershell command in Rstudio

Tags: r, powershell

I want to execute in Rstudio this powershell command

```
[System.IO.File]::ReadLines(".\Dropbox\TesisGrado\R_Data\rawdata\5.Azules\200 ppfd\65.dm68i.e.r.1.dat")
```

I've tried many ways like

```
system( "[System.IO.File]::ReadLines", input= ".\\65.dm68i.e.r.1.dat")

shell("[System.IO.File]::ReadLines", input= ".\\Dropbox\\TesisGrado\\R_Data\\rawdata\\5.Azules\\200\ ppfd\\65.dm68i.e.r.1.dat")

system("cmd.exe", input = paste("powershell [System.IO.File]::ReadLines(\".\\Dropbox\\TesisGrado\\R_Data\\rawdata\\5.Azules\\200\ ppfd\\65.dm68i.e.r.1.dat\")"))

system("cmd.exe", input = paste("powershell [System.IO.File]::ReadLines(\"65.dm68i.e.r.1.dat\")"))
```

Getting this kind of error

```
Microsoft Windows [Versi¢n 10.0.16299.192]
(c) 2017 Microsoft Corporation. Todos los derechos reservados.

    C:\Users\Admin\Dropbox\TesisGrado\R_Data\rawdata\5.Azules\200 ppfd>powershell [System.IO.File]::ReadLines("65.dm68i.e.r.1.dat")
    En l¡nea: 1 Car cter: 29
    + [System.IO.File]::ReadLines(65.dm68i.e.r.1.dat)
    +                             ~
    Falta el par‚ntesis de cierre ')' en la llamada al m‚todo.
    En l¡nea: 1 Car cter: 29
    + [System.IO.File]::ReadLines(65.dm68i.e.r.1.dat)
    +                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Token '65.dm68i.e.r.1.dat' inesperado en la expresi¢n o la instrucci¢n.
    En l¡nea: 1 Car cter: 47
    + [System.IO.File]::ReadLines(65.dm68i.e.r.1.dat)
    +                                               ~
    Token ')' inesperado en la expresi¢n o la instrucci¢n.
        + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
        + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingEndParenthesisInMethodCall
     
    
    C:\Users\Admin\Dropbox\TesisGrado\R_Data\rawdata\5.Azules\200 ppfd>[1] 0
```

My current directory in Rstudio is C:/Users/Admin/Dropbox/TesisGrado/R_Data/rawdata/5.Azules/200 ppfd/

What i'm doing wrong? How can i read that file executing powershell command?

Comment: R's `system` and `system2` do not deal well with arguments that have embedded spaces. I suggest using the `ps` package.

Answer (score 1):

In Rstudio, system() works just by specifying the file name, if you are in the directory that contains it. In PowerShell you must specify the full path, no matter if you are in the folder or not. Hence,

```
system2("cmd.exe", input = paste("powershell [System.IO.File]::ReadLines('.\\65.dm68i.e.r.1.dat')"))
```

The above code works. I had to change the quotation.

Comment: Your answer is very difficult to understand. I think you should rephrase the first sentence.

Comment: Like it now? Thanks

Comment: Yeah, Mauro, https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/69685195/2 is much better. Thanks.